ttk.PanedWindow.sashpos(ind, n) does not set the sash position while dragging
this is the code (note that this is mrp code):
def enforce_sash_limits(self, event):
    self.main_paned_win.sashpos(0, 120)

def init_pagebrowser(self):
    self.main_paned_win = ttk.PanedWindow(self.pages_area_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL) 
    self.slides_pane = tk.Frame(self.main_paned_win, bg=colorconsts.BG_COLOR)
    self.slides_pane.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.main_paned_win.add(self.slides_pane, weight=3)
    self.preview_pane = tk.Frame(self.main_paned_win, bg="magenta")
    self.preview_pane.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.main_paned_win.add(self.preview_pane, weight=2)
    self.main_paned_win.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.slides_area_class = SlidesArea(self.slides_pane)
    self.slides_area_class.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    self.main_paned_win.bind("\<B1-Motion\>", self.enforce_sash_limits) #<-----

I expected that everytime I drag the sash, the sash would fix itself to a specific position. But it doesnt and just lets itself be drags whatever it likes. How to solve this? I dont want to switch to tk.PanedWindow because I had layering issues with that one.
If that's helpful, I am in Fedora Worksation 41

If you don't want draggable sashes, then what is the point of using a PanedWindow at all?  Just .grid() or .pack() your individual Frames into the containing Frame, you have options like weight= and expand= to control how they take up space.

Try adding return 'break' at the end of self.enforce_sash_limits() to disable the default handling.  Note that it is not necessary to call .pack() on the frames that added to the paned window.
